# Error on Installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, login

Honestly I have no idea what this error could be or could stem from so I will just give as much information as possible.

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but the main issue I am having is I cannot boot into Ubuntu properly. I downloaded the iso from ubuntu.com, and installed it to a usb by means of Rufus and Universal usb installer, and I have even tried installing as a DD which I am not clear on what that means. I even redownloaded it thinking it might have an error, and used different ports on my computer and different thumb drives and I am still getting the same error.

Whenever I boot into Ubuntu it comes up and asks if I would like to try or install, no matter what I choose from there I get a bunch of graphical explosions which may not be errors and after some time I am presented with a login. There is my first problem, I do not believe I should have to login, should I not be setting my login? At any rate, I looked up the default login and it is ubuntu and blank on password. This seems to work but then a dialog box pops up saying "System Program Error" or something along those lines asking me to report, and then after a second it turns black and then disappears and takes me back to the login. Call for terminal does not work at all (not entirely sure it is supposed to) and then I were to wait on the login screen for more than five minutes, whether I try to log in or not, It will say authentication failed and be stuck with a retry button that seemingly does nothing. I have no idea what to do at this point. I would appreciate any help anyone can give.

Computer Specs if it is important:

- Intel i7-6700k 4.0GHz
- Gigabyte GA-Z170XP-sli ATX motherboard
- Adata 16GB ddr4-24000
- 2 MSI Geforce GTX 960 4GB Video card in SLI
- Windows 10 (if it makes a difference)

Thank you so much for your time, I appreciate anything.

So upon suggestion I am able to get into the tty6 and log in in a way. I am still looking to install the OS, could it be that it is a graphical error and it has difficulty displaying things? Could it be I need specific drivers? I'm sorry you'll have to excuse me I have never used this screen before and I'm not quite sure how to fix it myself.

New edit:
So I went in and I tried to update the drivers involved and then went back and tried to log in with the user friendly version, which I assume is tty7, and the whole screen went black. Then I tried to go back to where I was using the command suggested, CTRL+ALT+F6 and it did this: [Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6NVL.jpg) Note: There was no key that was pressed, the command was being continually run I suppose.

The error says:

```
Error: Driver 'ebridge' is already registered, aborting...
nvidia-nvlink: alloc_chrdev_region failed: -16
```

Comment: Once you install Ubuntu, you're removing the installation USB and booting off of your HDD/SSD, right? During the installation, you set up a first user by setting up that name and password. Are you not able to get this far in the installation? Are you able to switch tty with CTRL+ALT+F6 and CTRL+ALT+F7. Can you login here? Edit your question with any updates you have.

Comment: The issue is installing Ubuntu. This is the first boot from the pen drive. I am just trying to install the OS, but it isn't usable from the boot to do anything. I used the command you gave and I am able to log in, but I do not know what to do with this in particular. But it does seems like I am in and it is somewhat stable. What should I do from here? Only tty6 worked.

Comment: Using 'dd' will NOT install Ubuntu. It will merely copy the installer environment. That's why you boot into a choice of 'try' or 'install'. Reinstall properly using the USB install media - dd overwrote whatever you installed before. You create your admin user login as part of the install.

Comment: Your comment disappeared but thank you so much to whoever suggested that article, that is what fixed my problem and got me into the system. On to other problems now!